# Unable to use debian/rules clean

Tags: command-line, compiling

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying to use the command `fakeroot debian/rules clean` but it errors out. Here is some of what is shown:

```
cp debian.master/control.stub debian/control.stub
cd /home/clmoore3/ubuntu-trusty/debian/build && kernel-wedge gen-control > /home/clmoore3/ubuntu-trusty/debian/control
/bin/bash: kernel-wedge: command not found
make: *** [debian/control] Error 127
```

Answer (score 10):

Installing `kernel-wedge` using the following command solved the problem:

`sudo apt-get install kernel-wedge`

Comment: Whoever downvoted, it would be great if you could explain the reason.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did, and then the debian/rules clean worked

Comment: Its good to know that the issue has been resolved. If the reputation permits please select it as the correct answer to your question so that this issue can be marked as solved.